# Подскажите,почему функция не воспроизводится,и при любых входных коэффициентах(где дискриминант больше 0)выдает "id"?

Tags: python

Подскажите,почему функция не воспроизводится,и при любых входных коэффициентах (где дискриминант больше 0) выдает “id”?

```
import math
print("Запишите коэффициенты данного квадратного уравнения: ax^2 + bx + c = 0 ")
def cof(d, e, f):
    return (d ** 2 - 4 * e * f)
def root1(b, cof, a):
    return (- b + math.sqrt(cof())) / (2 * a)
def root2(b, cof, a):
    return (- b - math.sqrt(cof())) / (2 * a)

a = float(input("a = "))
b = float(input("b = "))
c = float(input("c = "))
if (a != 1):
    #Disk = cof(a, b, c)
    if (cof(a, b, c) > 0):
        print("Дискриминант D = %.2f" % (cof(a, b, c)))
    else:
        print("ld")
```

Comment: P.S Функция,о которой идет речь:def cof(d, e, f):
    return (d ** 2 - 4 * e * f)    ,   коэффициентов*

Comment: Запишите коэффициенты данного квадратного уравнения: ax^2 + bx + c = 0 
a = 16
b = 8
c = 1
Дискриминант D = 224.00 Это то что выводит в консоль, ваша программа у меня работает

Comment: Совет: если что-то идёт не так, выводите на печать. print(cof(a,b,c)) показало бы вам, что вычисляется неправильно.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Потому, что вы задаете такие данные.

Введите, например  a = 100, b = 2, c = 3

И благополучно получите

```
Дискриминант D = 9976.00
```

Так что просто задайте правильный набор данных.

Comment: Да, только дискриминант для уравнения с  коэффициентами `a=100`, `b=2`, `c=3` равен `-1196`. Дело не во входных данных

Comment: Я  не знаю, какой там дискриминант. И не про математические ошибки была речь. Вопрос был -  почему программа идет не по той ветке, которую ожидал автор. И я ему именно это и объяснил.А вы ему математику править решили. Так что зря вы с минусом то горячитесь.

Comment: @passant а программа как раз и идёт не по той ветке, потому что неправильная.

Comment: @Эникейщик Никак нет. Читаем внимательно вопрос "почему функция не воспроизводится,и при любых входных коэффициентах(где дискриминант больше 0)выдает “id”?" Я показал, что программа НЕ ПРИ ВСЕХ коэффициентах (входных данных) выдает "ld". А что там программа делает и почему она считает дискриминант с ошибкой - это совершенно другой вопрос.

Comment: Вам уже написали, что для ваших данных дискриминант МЕНЬШЕ  нуля.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что для большей наглядности следует помнить о значащих именах переменных. Вы передаёте в `cof` аргументы `(a, b, c)`, и, исходя из тела этой функции, считаете дискриминант по формуле `a**2 - 4*b*c`. В то же время реальная формула - `b**2 - 4*a*c`.

Именно из-за абстрактных `d, e, f` вы и не увидели эту ошибку

```py
import math
print("Запишите коэффициенты данного квадратного уравнения: ax^2 + bx + c = 0 ")
def cof(a, b, c):
    return (b**2 - 4*a*c)

def root1(b, cof, a):
    return (- b + math.sqrt(cof())) / (2 * a)

def root2(b, cof, a):
    return (- b - math.sqrt(cof())) / (2 * a)

a = float(input("a = "))
b = float(input("b = "))
c = float(input("c = "))
if (a != 1):
    if (cof(a, b, c) > 0):
        print("Дискриминант D = %.2f" % (cof(a, b, c)))
    else:
        print("ld")
```

```
Запишите коэффициенты данного квадратного уравнения: ax^2 + bx + c = 0 
a = 2
b = 5
c = 2
Дискриминант D = 9.00
```